# Why doesn't Rules Conditional recognize a hidden field value?

Tags: rules

I'm using Drupal 7.

I have a simple "email confirmation" system set up using rules. The setup is this:

1. "Reservation" Content Type has a boolean check box for "confirmed".
2. "Reservation" Content Type has a **hidden** boolean check box for "confirmation email sent"
3. Both #1 and #2 are empty by default.

Here is the Rules flow once an Admin checks "confirmed":

1. Rules checks for "reservation" content type update.
2. Rules validates two conditions: (1) "confirmed" == true AND (2) "email sent" == empty
3. A confirmation email is sent to the user making the "reservation"
4. The "email sent" field is set = true.

The system works fine if I make the "email sent" field **visible** in the "reservation" Content Type, but if it is **hidden** then the system breaks. When working correctly it sends exactly one email. When broken it sends emails every time the content changes.

When it is **hidden** the Rules flow still changes the value of "email sent" = true. It just doesn't validate it during the conditional phase.

This flummoxes me. Why would it not validate hidden field values?

```
{ "rules_reservation_confirmed" : {
    "LABEL" : "Reservation Confirmed",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_update--lc_space_reservation" : { "bundle" : "lc_space_reservation" } },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:field-confirmed-" ], "value" : "1" } },
      { "AND" : [ { "data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "node:field-email-sent" ] } } ] }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : "[node:field-email-address]",
          "subject" : "Your Language Commons reservation [node:title] is now confirmed.",
          "message" : "Your Language Commons reservation \u003Cem\u003E[node:title]\u003C\/em\u003E is now confirmed. Please click on \u003Ca href=\u0022[node:url]\u0022\u003Ethis link\u003C\/a\u003E for more information about your reservation. Please reply to this email with questions. ",
          "from" : "languagecommons@virginia.edu",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "node:field-email-sent" ], "value" : "1" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: please update your question to include an export of your rule you have so far. that might help to understand the "Rules Conditional" part of your question ... PS: I can think of 2 possible causes for your issue, bit I first want to see your rule (toavoid guessing) ...

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks for your help. I'll add the export to the original post.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Hey Pierre, forgot to hit the at key (not sure if that helps or not). Thanks for responding; see above.